# CSV iterate/loop

Tags: loops, csv

I am trying to iterate through all the cells of a CSV row ( name, screen_name and image url). Different errors show up, I tried with pandas but still I am unable to finish the job. My CSV looks like this:

```
screen_name,name,image_url_https
Jan,Jan,https://twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png
greg,Gregory Kara,https://twimg.com/profile_images/60709109/Ferran_Adria_normal.jpg
hillheadshow,Hillhead 2020,https://twimg.com/profile_images/1192061150915178496/cF6jOCRV_normal.jpg
hectaresbe,Hectaresbe,https://twimg.com/profile_images/1190957150996226048/lJnRnFwi_normal.jpg
Sdzz,Sanne,https://twimg.com/profile_images/1159005129879801856/8p6KC1ei_normal.jpg
```

and the part of the code that I need to change is:

```
import json
import time,os
import pandas as pd

screen_name = 'mylist'

file = pd.read_csv("news2.csv", header=0)

col = file.head(0)

columns = list(col)

fp=codecs.open(screen_name+'.csv','w',encoding="utf-8")
i=0
while True:
    try:
        i+=1
        print (i)
        name=['name']
        uname=['screen_name']
        urlimage=['image_url_https']
```

The values are ok with @Snake_py code, next i am doing a request:

```
myrequest='https://requesturl.com/'+uname
#print(myrequest)
resp=requests.get(myrequest)
```

I get the following error:

```
raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '0    https://requesturl.com/Jan
```

Name: name, dtype: object'

timeout error caught.

Comment: Can you add in the errors you're getting

Comment: i tried so many possibilities that i really can't paste them here. I managed to print one value at a time from a single row with dataframes pandas. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way to iterate through a csv with Python would be:

```
name = []
uname = []
urlimage =[]

open with ('url', 'r') as file:
  for row in file:
     row = row.strip().split(";")
     name.append(row[0])
     uname.append(row[1])
     urlimage.append(row[2])

print(name)
print(uname)
print(urlimage)
```

First I created three empty arrays. then I open the file and iterate over each row in the file. Row will be returned as an array. So you can run the normal index command [] to get the needed part of the array to append it to the empty list.
For the method above you might run into an encoding problem, so I would recommend method 2, although you actually do not iterate over the rows then.

Alternatively you could just do:

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv("news2.csv", header=0)

name = file['name']
uname = file['uname']
urlimage = file['urlimage']
```

For the second method, you need to make sure that your header has the correct spelling

Comment: Good point, but i don't know how to write every cell in name, uname, url-image. I am a totally newbie, pasting examples codes will not work for my skills :0. Thanks

Comment: What do you wanna do with your rows?

Comment: Get the values of the cells here:  name=['name']  ;  uname=['screen_name']  ; urlimage=['image_url_https']   . I have the rest of the script which works fine. Thanks for the interest shown! really appreciate

Comment: I edit my answer, I hope it is more understandable now. It would really help if you would paste your date into your question, just 5 lines, so people can see what you want to achieve and from where your starting.

Comment: I edited my question since i can;t paste the entire error here